# Update to Commerce shipping 2.x breaks site with WSOD

Tags: commerce

Implementing shipping 2 is becoming a bit more troublesome than i had anticipated.

Right now, I am getting the following error on a White Screen of Death when I install commerce shipping 7.x-2.0-beta1

Fatal error: Call to undefined function commerce_shipping_services() in /var/www/html/nidadev/sites/all/modules/contrib/commerce_shipping/commerce_shipping.rules_defaults.inc on line 44

I am not sure what to make of this Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Is there some sort of update to rules I need to perform?

The problem goes away when I go back down to Shipping 1

This issue is standing in our way of working with Tim Rohaly on the Fed Ex Commerce module, so the quicker we fix this, the quicker he can get his code out to the community.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

The 7.x-2 branch of Commerce Shipping is only in beta, it's not ready for production use yet (but you probably already know that).

The [release notes](http://drupal.org/node/1371406) for the branch warn you not to install this on a site that currently uses v1.x of the shipping module:

> **Note: If you are currently using Shipping 1.x on a live site, do not attempt an update on your live site. See the roadmap below for more information.**

(emphasis theirs, not mine!)

I would heed that warning if I were you :)

Comment: Thanks for your input! We have this on our DEV site now, but since we are working with <tr> on Fed Ex, I thought it may be best to work with Shipping 2.

Comment: If you're on a dev site you're most likely ok to use the beta version...just make sure you uninstall the 1.x version first and it'll probably be ok :)

Comment: Good idea - I already tried that and it didn't work, though

Comment: Hmm... dang it! In that case it might be worth starting a post in the [module issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_shipping?categories=All), I haven't found anything similar in there as yet so this might be a new bug :)

Comment: If you haven't already done this, make sure to install Commerce Shipping 2.x on a clean Commerce Kickstart site and see if you get this error. This is so blatant that it's a bit surprising. I *recommend* shipping 2.x, as it's the only thing that works with Flat Rate, and is the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out part of the problem - We did not have the payment module enabled and that was causing some issues. It seems that Shipping has a dependency on Payment. Since our site distributes free publications, we were not using the payment module.